# Django readonly_fields not showing data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

My `Orders` model has a `rate` and `total_amount` field. I had to derive the rate from the different models so I created `unit_rate`.

Similarly, I wanted my `total_amount` fields to be a multiplication of `quantity` and `unit_rate`, which I tried by doing `total_pay`.

Here is my code:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def unit_rate(self,obj):
        self.rate = Product.objects.get(pk=obj.order_id)
        return self.rate.price

    def total_pay(self,obj):
        self.rate = Product.objects.get(pk=obj.order_id)
        self.total_amount = self.rate.price * obj.quantity
        return self.total_amount

    list_display = ('order_id', 'order_item', 'order_status', 'delivery_address', 'customer',
        'quantity','unit_rate','total_pay')

    readonly_fields = ('total_pay','unite_rate')

admin.site.register(Orders,OrderAdmin)
```

As `total_pay` and `unit_rate` are obtained from other columns, the admin doesn't need to enter them. That's why I kept them on `readonly_fields`.

The problem is that, whenever it creates an order through the admin interface, `total_pay` and `unit_rate` do not show up in the admin. It just shows a dash like this: `-`.

It has been doing this for a while, so I could really use your help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you register those models in admin.py ? may be you did but i'm just asking cauz you didn't mentiened it

Comment: yes , i registered them in admin right above this code but i thought that is not important so just shared required code. If you think that was important i can share that as well

Answer (score 0):

Actually digging little bit more for hours i found the solution.

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('order_id', 'order_item', 'order_status', 'delivery_address', 'customer',
        'quantity','unit_rate','total_pay')

    def unit_rate(self,obj):
        rate = Product.objects.get(pk=obj.order_item.product_id)
        return rate.price

    def total_pay(self,obj):
        rate = Product.objects.get(pk=obj.order_item.product_id)
        total_amount = rate.price * obj.quantity
        return total_amount

admin.site.register(Orders,OrderAdmin)
```

Actually i did not know how to pass `product_id` along with `order_item`. and i think even documentation is also does not help much.